# How to run simple python script on web

Tags: python, web, python-module

What is the simplest way of running a python script on the web?

I've been learning to use python to create really simple scripts that scrape the web and represent that data as HTML that can be cut-and-pasted into our CMS.

I'd like to share the technology with my colleagues without forcing them to install python on their machines and thought the web would be a great solution.

I've seen solutions ranging from Django to Flask, Tornado to Python On Wheels but I'm just getting overwhelmed by lots of server-speak.

Can anyone suggest a framework that makes it simple for newbies to get started and develop as I get more experience?

Secondary question: how easy - or not - would it be to have modules available to bolster the toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying Google App Engine. Some details here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in scraping maybe [scraperwiki](https://scraperwiki.com/docs/python/python_intro_tutorial/) is something for you. It allows you to build scrapers in python and it handles the storage.

And otherwise maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795315/is-there-a-good-free-small-python-web-host) has the answer.

Comment: I did learn to scrape using Scraperwiki, but I'm slowly getting to the point where I'd like to stretch my wings a bit into other things. It's just that transition has proved more scary than I thought. Thank you, though. It is a great platform to learn on.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up in apache with [WSGI](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#wsgi) quite easily.. although not sure which OS you're runnin on the server.

For Ubuntu 12.04:

First, install Apache's module:

```
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Then, restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then you can add [a simple example program](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#module-cgi) to test; install it in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` then, just run from `http://your-domain/cgi-bin/your-script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

print "Content-Type: text/html"     # needed to indicate that the content is HTML
print                               # blank line, end of headers, don't remove

print "Hello World!"
```

Hope that helps!